# Add Marker to Custom Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I was just wondering, how would I add a marker to the coordinates (38.0, -98.0) and another marker to the coordinates (45.0, -100.0) to a custom Google Map I'm making? So far, this is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;
  var grayStyles = [
    {
      featureType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -100 },
      ]
    },
  ];
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -98),
    zoom: 5,
    styles: grayStyles,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you seen the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)?

Comment: I looked at it, yes. I'm really new to most coding so I'm just trying to teach myself and the documentation just seemed a bit daunting to me. But thank you for answering my question below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple markers:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.0, -98.0),
      map: map,
  });

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0, -100.0),
      map: map,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I used, to be placed after the line

```
map = new google.maps.Map(documen......
```

And You can repeat this code many times to get more markers

```
  var ncenter = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('52.43598') , parseFloat('16.94412'));  /* this is the position */ 
  var image = {
    url: '/img/xspot.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
    size: new google.maps.Size(115, 86),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(57, 71)
  }; /* You can ignore the image mark */ 
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ncenter,
      map: map,
      icon: image // if you ignore image related code above, also remove this line
  });
```